# Can't seed my database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I started doing a new project days ago, and want to add a static table on my project to do that I'm trying to work with the seed on Asp.net mvc, I already added a static table to my role table that already exist, but when I try to seed a table that I created it can't find the attributes of my class, in this example description appears underlined cause it can't find it.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CrowdTouring2.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "CrowdTouring2.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
    }

    // Cria as tabelas estaticas no sistema
    protected override void Seed(CrowdTouring2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if(!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Admin"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" };
            manager.Create(role);
        }

        if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Cliente"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Cliente" };
            manager.Create(role);
        }

        if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Resolvedor"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Resolvedor" };
            manager.Create(role);
        }

        if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Avaliador"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Avaliador" };
            manager.Create(role);
        }

        var conta = new List<EstadoConta>
        {
            new EstadoConta { descricao = "Admin"}
        };


    }
}
```

**I have my dbSet on the identity model like this:**

```
    using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace CrowdTouring2.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<EstadoConta> EstadosConta { get; set; }
}
```

}

**my class**

```
    namespace CrowdTouring2.Models
{
    public class EstadoConta
    {
        public int EstadoContaId { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var conta = new List<EstadoConta>
    {
        new EstadoConta { descricao = "Admin"}  
 }; 
   conta.ForEach(s => context.contas.AddOrUpdate(p => p.descricao, s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Same problem, i already saw this solution the problem is that he cant recognize the descricao :S

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.